# jqGrid select with asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm having a problem with **jqGrid**'s select type.On the server I use an `IdName` class. I made a custom formatter to format both `IdName` and `string` values:

```
formatSelect = function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

        if(typeof cellvalue === 'object')
        {
            cellvalue = cellvalue.Name;
        }

        return cellvalue;
```

My problem is that on post it only sends the `Id` and it doesn't map back to `IdName`.

The editoptions is use:

```
 {
     dataUrl: controller + action,
     buildSelect: buildSelect,
     defaultValue: '',
     NullIfEmpty: true
 }

 buildSelect = function (data) {
        var selectTag = '<select>';
        selectTag += '<option class="selectPlaceholder" selected>Select...</option>'
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, value) {
            if (typeof value === "object") selectTag += '<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Name + '</option>';
            else selectTag += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
        });
        return selectTag += '</select>';
    }
```

Comment: show your controller please

Comment: I have two controller action, both of them returns a JsonNetResult. for the grid there is a viewmodel which have an IdName property. And in for the other action there is just an IEnumerable<IdName> for the selector

Comment: i don't get what you trying to achive. You create select list. By default if you submit form it will send values from value attribute. if you want to get Name also you should create hidden field i suppose. Just don't see full picture.